# S11108 CMOS linear image sensor not working

Tags: arduino, sensor, cmos, ccd

I'm looking for help/advise working with a S11108 is a CMOS linear image sensor. My son is studying computer science at university who has  been helping. We are using the S11108 to scan a moving object which is a plastic tape like product that has a gap in the middle running down the length of the material. The gap changes changes size and we would like to monitor this. Please see my circuit design. I believe the sensor is capable of doing the job. However we are doing something wrong with regards to the programming or maybe circuit design. For whatever reason we don’t seem to be getting anything on the video output line or end of signal line after S11108 sensor. Could anyone on here point me into the right direction as to what the problem may be? Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the point of that circuit, in general, like please describe how do you expect it to work and what does it do instead? E.g how/why do you expect this to work at all, instead of damaging something? Have you made any measurements what voltages or currents you get, and what they should be?

Comment: What frequency are you running the clock? Can that Arduino even reach the minimum pixel clock frequency on its ADC?

Comment: @justme From what I've seen of these sensors online and from this sensor in particular I need to see a 0.5 voltage offset on the video line plus whatever video data is meant to come out at that point in time. Additionally I'm meant to be seeing a periodic pulse on the end of signal line which I'm not seeing either. So far both the EOS and Video lines are outputting 0v

Comment: @user1850479 I have just checked this again and I'm hesitant to say whether it does, just from some rough data I've found online it looks as though the ADC may only be able to sample at ~122Hz. This may need double checking but if I'm correct do you have any suggestions on a board that may serve as a replacement.

Comment: Some other problems: you don't have all the power and ground pins connected and you need to decouple all of them. The datasheet has an example schematic with the recommended decoupling. But stepping back, you have a relatively high data rate sensor hooked up an extremely slow microcontroller. Even if you fix all the problems and get the sensor working I don't think you'll have enough CPU cycles or memory to do anything useful with the image data, presuming you can even capture it with the available hardware.

Comment: @user1850479 thank you for replying, I've actually been to a couple forums and asked the same question in a couple other forums and they have all said along the same lines that the Arduino isnt great for this application. Do you have any recommendations for microcontrollers that may be appropriate for this project? Furthermore, I shall update my schematic and design to make sure all the pins are connected and decoupled.

Comment: You need something with a fast enough ADC for the data rate, enough memory to store the data you'll generate during processing and a fast enough CPU to do the processing. I don't know what your needs are so I don't have a specific recommendation but probably some kind of higher end ARM CPU and an ADC with a DMA engine that can stream data in for you would be a good start. Alternatively, look for a sensor with the ADC integrated so that you don't have to build all the hardware yourself.